# Python macOS Uninstallation issue

Tags: python, uninstallation

I want to cleanup my python installations on macOS Monterey 12.6.

So have some executable (not symlink) file `python3` in my `/usr/bin/` which I can't remove due to permission denied error. I try use *sudo* but it didn't help.
How to remove one?

Also I checked `/usr/lib/` but there are no any python *site-packages* there.

But I found ones in `/usr/local/lib/`.

So how I can determine that site-packages bind to that `/usr/bin/python3`?

Please advise.

Comment: You probably shouldn't touch anything under `/usr/bin`; that's for the OS itself to manage.

Comment: Yes, but macOS starting 12.3 has no longer preinstalled any python. I supposed that deprecated python interpreter and want to remove it..

Comment: So this is an upgrade, rather than a clean install on a new machine? You *still* don't know if some other bit installed by a previous OS might be using the older things.

Comment: better don't unistall existing `Python` because system may need it to run some functions.